# Crystal Reports printing pauses between pages

Tags: crystal-reports, printing

When we print a crystal report using crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport(); the printers pause between pages and the client have to press a button in the printer to print the next page. If the client uses the report viewer print button it works fine.

It happens in these printers:
-HP CLJ 3600
-OKI C5450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we make it work by calling the reportdocument print function instead of the reportviewer's reportDoc.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, 1000);

Dont know if Graham awnser is ok thought if someone confirms this i will mark as correct answer too...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that happen when the report is set up for a different paper size than the printer is expecting - ie: your report is setup for A4 and the printer contains 8 1/2 x 11.